# Pass string as parameter in assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I have to write assembly equivalent of a c code that looks like this:

```
void fun_name(char *array)
```

I know I have to pass this value to %edi register in order to pass it as first param to function fun_name. How do I encode this value?

Comment: What's the value you want to send to `fun_name()`?

Comment: @l'L'l The value is a string equivalent of a hex value say: 0x14ac0baa.

Comment: If it's a string value though I think you'll want to use `const char`

Comment: @l'L'l Okay but this is what I've got. I have to convert this to machine code. Any clues how this can be done?

Comment: You're definitely on the right track, all you should need to do is move `array` to `%edi`...  so (`movl $array, %edi`, then `call fun_name`).

Comment: You tagged this as x86-64, so the caller puts the pointer arg in `%rdi`, and the called-function uses `%rdi`.  Using `%esi` will work until you encounter a pointer that has some bits set in the high 32.  (e.g. pointers to stack memory in Linux are high addresses.)  There are useful links for x86-64, including the ABI, at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info